# Any workaround to launch exported='false' app?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I want to launch Cardboard Camera straight into VR mode. I found, that Cardboard Camera app (id=`com.google.vr.cyclops`) has `CardboardViewerActivity`, although it's not exported (I've decompiled the app and I see in `AndroidManifest.xml` it has `exported="false"` flag.

Although, I tried starting The activity with this Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(VRAppDetailActivity.this, VRAppDetailActivity.class);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.vr.cyclops", "com.google.android.apps.cyclops.CardboardViewerActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

But I'm getting this error

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { cmp=com.google.vr.cyclops/com.google.android.apps.cyclops.CardboardViewerActivity } from ProcessRecord{3361e2bb 31396:lt.andro.myapplication/u0a322} (pid=31396, uid=10322) not exported from uid 10306
```

Anyone knows how to workaround this `SecurityException` and run the Cardboard Camera in VR mode?

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone knows how to workaround this SecurityException

You can't. The authors of that app decided that this activity should only be launched by itself, not by others. That's not something that you can change, short of joining that development team and convincing them to export the activity, then ship the updated app to everyone.

Comment: Yeah... I knew this was coming. 

Although I like The workaround "joining that development team". :)

Comment: @ViliusK: Hey, for all I know, they're hiring. :-)